# A way to drop cross validation models in GridSearch?

Tags: h2o

I keep running out of memory building Random Forest models in H2O in Jupyter notebook. I find that with my 20 GB memory instance, I can build approximately two 50-tree models with 10-fold cross validation (22 total models) before it throws the "tree model will not fit in driver node's memory" exception. With a for loop, I can remove the cross validation models after the metrics have been calculated and displayed, but with GridSearch, there doesn't seem to be any way to drop the extraneous CV models while searching. Is this the case? Is there any sort of workaround? (I can always increase the amount of memory allocated, but that ultimately will be a finite value running on my local machine). Does anyone have any tips for GridSearch and limited memory? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a reasonable request and there's not currently a way to do this in H2O's grid search functionality, however I have created a ticket [here](https://0xdata.atlassian.net/browse/PUBDEV-5745).  There is another [ticket open](https://0xdata.atlassian.net/browse/PUBDEV-4053) for a similar request, which is to keep the "top k" models from the grid (and delete the rest) as you continue to run the grid search.

We have implemented this functionality for [H2O AutoML](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/automl.html) via the `keep_cross_validation_models` argument, so if you're open to using H2O AutoML (which would be mostly GBMs), you could use that instead of a Random Forest grid.  If you set this argument to `FALSE`, then CV models will be deleted, however the only [problem](https://0xdata.atlassian.net/browse/PUBDEV-5746) with the current implementation is that the CV models are deleted at the end of the AutoML run instead of immediately after they are created and CV metrics are saved.

So, in the meantime, for a work-around, I'd recommend the following:

You can execute the grid more than once by making use of the `grid_id` argument.  After each execution, you can manually delete the CV models.  Then you can "train" the grid again and set `grid_id` to be the same as before and it will add more models to the same grid.  If you are using cartesian grid search, you should change the search space, and if you are using random grid search, you can just change the seed so that you'll get different/new models the second time around.  It's manual, but it's still a bit easier than writing a loop and creating the grid from scratch.

Python Example:

```
import h2o
from h2o.estimators.random_forest import H2ORandomForestEstimator
from h2o.grid.grid_search import H2OGridSearch

h2o.init()

# Import a sample binary outcome training set into H2O
train = h2o.import_file("https://s3.amazonaws.com/erin-data/higgs/higgs_train_10k.csv")
x = train.columns
y = "response"
x.remove(y)

# For binary classification, response should be a factor
train[y] = train[y].asfactor()

# RF hyperparameters
rf_params = {'max_depth': list(range(5, 30)),
             'sample_rate': [i * 0.1 for i in range(5, 11)],
             'min_rows': list(range(1, 25))}

# Search criteria
search_criteria = {'strategy': 'RandomDiscrete', 'max_models': 20}

rf_grid = H2OGridSearch(model=H2ORandomForestEstimator,
                        grid_id='rf_grid',
                        hyper_params=rf_params,
                        search_criteria=search_criteria)
rf_grid.train(x=x, y=y, 
              training_frame=train, 
              nfolds=5, 
              ntrees=300,
              seed=1)

# Code to delete CV models (you'll have to do this part)

rf_grid.train(x=x, y=y, 
              training_frame=train, 
              nfolds=5, 
              ntrees=300,
              seed=2)  #change seed for second random grid search run
```